# NEXTAUTH_URL in Ubuntu

Tags: next.js, next-auth, ubuntu-22.04

I have decided to deploy my NextJS (13.3.1) and Next-Auth (4.22.1) app to an Ubuntu VM.
There is not much documentation on this unfortunately.

What should I set my NEXTAUTH_URL to?

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://example.com
```

Should it be set in .env.production or as an Ubuntu environment variable in etc/environments ?

I have nginx as a proxy forwarding everything to localhost:3000

Thanks!